Rearrange elements depending on window dimensions
As shown on the picture, there are 4 small elements (green) and 1 large one (red). I want them to be placed in such way as shown, depending on the window's aspect ratio. I have tried to do it with CSS but with no success (I have little experience with it). Can it be done with CSS? Or some JavaScript is needed?


This can be done in a few ways, the most obvious being CSS Grid.

As already said, you can easily use CSS-Grid here.
Wrap the elements within a container that has display: grid and uses a 2-column layout by using grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr).
To make the red box larger as provided in the image, you have to assign grid-column: span 4; grid-row: span 4; to it.
Changing the layout can be done using media queries. You simply have to change to a 3-column layout and changing the placement to grid-auto-flow: column dense.


.d-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (width > 480px) {
  .d-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow: column dense;
  }
}

.red {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 4;
}


/* for demo purpose only */
.green {
  min-height: 20vh;
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
<div class="d-grid">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>



